# running EJB application

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I am following this tutorial : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI?_sscc=t

I am using only stateless bean part of it.
I am getting this exception

```
Obtained a remote stateless calculator for invocation
Adding 204 and 340 via the remote stateless calculator deployed on the server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:MyFirstEJBProj,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@5f9f89ee
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at trial_client.RemoteEJBClient.invokeStatelessBean(RemoteEJBClient.java:26)
    at trial_client.RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:16)
```

I am getting exception for this line: `int sum = statelessRemoteCalculator.add(a, b);`

My code is:

```
final RemoteCalculator statelessRemoteCalculator = lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator();
System.out.println("Obtained a remote stateless calculator for invocation");
// invoke on the remote calculator
int a = 204;
int b = 340;
System.out.println("Adding " + a + " and " + b + " via the remote stateless calculator deployed on the server");
int sum = statelessRemoteCalculator.add(a, b);
System.out.println("Remote calculator returned sum = " + sum);
if (sum != a + b) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Remote stateless calculator returned an incorrect sum " + sum + " ,expected sum was " + (a + b));
}
```

Am I missing out on any JARs?

I am running my client as "run a java application".

EDIT:
my `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false 
remote.connections=default 
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.default.username=appuser
remote.connection.default.password=apppassword
```

Answer (score 0):

the only library that you are supposed to add in your project/client application is \bin\client\jboss-client.jar